# Extraer una columna de nombres de MSQL y guardarla en un array PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, array

Lo que quiero es extraer los nombres de la base de datos y guardarlos en un array para despues con mostrarlos segun el orden como se guardo en el arreglo quiero guardarlo en el arreglo $alumno[]

```
    <?php
                               $nombre = array();
                                  include_once '../conexion.php';
                                  $mysqli = new mysqli($hostbd,$usuariobd,$clave,$basededatos);
                                    if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
                                      die("Fallo Conexion a MySQL");
                                    }
                                      else{
                                        $sql_query="SELECT Status,Alumno FROM computadoras WHERE Fila='1'";
                                        $resultado=$mysqli->query($sql_query);
                                          while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc())
                                            {
                                             $status[] = $row["Status"];
                                             $alumno[]= $row["Alumno"];
                                            }
                                  }
?>
```

**Esta es donde lo llamo a imprimir**

```
<div class="fila">

      <?php
      for ($i=0; $i <10 ; $i++) { 
        if ($status[$i]!=0) { 
      ?>
             <div id="info">
               <img id="foto" src="img/computer(1).png" alt="computer"><span>Disponible</span>
             </div>
        <?php
         }
         else{ ?>
           <div id="info">
              <img id="foto" src="img/computer.png" alt="computer"><span>Matricula: <?php echo $alumno[$i]; ?></span>
           </div>
            <?php
         }

      }

      ?>


</div>
```

El status si me funciona , porque solo es 1 o 0 si es 1 imprime otra cosa , pero cuando esta en uso quiero saber el nombre de quien lo esta usando

Comment: No se entiendo tu problema. Ahora lo estas guardando en dos array distintos.

Comment: En un array guardo un numero eso si me funciona, pero el el de alumnos tengo un nombre digamos "Daniel" pero son varios y al querer imprimir esos valores no me lo hace y con el de numeros y me lo imprime

Comment: no se que es no me lo hace. Ni se que hace. A la pregunta le falta lo que esperas recibir, lo que recibis realmente, y ademas que imprimis y como lo imprimis...

Comment: Ya modifique mi pregunta

Comment: No veo tus variables $status ni $alumno declaradas

Comment: estan en el while

Comment: Estás haciendo mal la declaración, esas variables deben ir fuera del while y ser declaradas como array para que puedas usar los índices

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podemos simplificar esto en algo más legible, te dejaré un ejemplo comentado. Tienes muchos errores de control de errores y validaciones, Pero creo que para este caso esto bastará, ocúpate de lo demás.

```
<?php
//Aqui está raro, por que estas incluyendo la conexión y la estas declarando con variables que ni existen
//Lo dejaré así pero debes corregirlo (A menos que uses dos conexiones)
include_once '../conexion.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostbd,$usuariobd,$clave,$basededatos);
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  die("Fallo Conexion a MySQL");
}

else{
  //Creamos una variable que contendrá nuestra información
  $data = array();
  $sql_query = "SELECT Status,Alumno FROM computadoras WHERE Fila='1'";
  $resultado = $mysqli->query( $sql_query );

  //Ciclamos el resultado
  while( $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ){
    //Agregamos al indice en curso y a los índices status y nombre 
    //Sus respectivos valores
    $data[]['status'] = (int) $row['Status'];
    $data[]['nombre'] = $row['Alumno'];
  }
}

//Defines una variable que tendrá todo tu HTML
$html = "";

//Empiezas a concatenar las piezas
$html .= '
<div class="fila">';

//Ciclas la variable data y sacas la información armando tu HTML
foreach( $data as $d ){
  if( $d['status'] === 0 ){
    $html .= '
    <div id="info">
      <img id="foto" src="img/computer.png" alt="computer"><span>Matricula: '. $d['nombre'] .'</span>
    </div>';
  }

  else{
    '<div id="info">
      <img id="foto" src="img/computer(1).png" alt="computer"><span>Disponible</span>
    </div>';
  }
}

$html .='</div>';

//Al final imprimes tu variable del HTML
echo $html;
?>
```